# SQL find rows where value is not increasing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns like this:

```
id | timestamp | ...
```

and I am looking for rows where the timestamp *decreased* since the previous row.

I tried a statement like this:

```
SELECT count(a.id)
FROM tbl AS a INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON a.id+1=b.id
WHERE a.timestamp<b.timestamp;
```

but it appears not to have worked. I get zero results even though I expect some. Any suggestions what is wrong?

I would also appreciate any ideas on a better way to write this query.

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the previous value using a correlated subquery, and then use that for the comparison:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.timestamp from tbl t2 where t2.id < t.id order by t2.id desc limit 1
             ) as prevts
      from tbl t
     ) t
where timestamp < prevts;
```

The problem with your query is probably that the ids have gaps in them.

EDIT:

You can do this with variables.  The challenge is getting the variable comparison and assignment in a single expression.  This is needed because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select` statement.

The following assigns a value to `IsDecreasing` and assigns the values:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             if(@prev > timestamp, if(@prev := timestamp, 1, 1),
                if(@prev := timestamp, 0, 0)
               ) IsDecreasing
      from tbl t cross join
           (select @prev := -1) vars
      order by id
     ) t
where IsDecreasing = 1;
```

This should be faster than the previous method -- probably even when you have the right index.

Comment: It is true - the ids did have gaps which I was not expecting. Your method looks more robust although it is running much more slowly.